# Descargar archivos de un subdominio

Tags: html, html5, descarga, enlace

Os explico el caso, tengo dos servidores (A y B).

La página esta alojada en el servidor A y los archivos descargables en el servidor B. El servidor A tiene el dominio principal y el servidor B un subdominio del principal accesibles los dos desde la web.

El problema esta en que cuando creo un enlace de descarga apuntando al subdominio del servidor B me abre el archivo en el navegador en lugar de descargarlo.

El enlace seria asi:

`<a href="http://subdominio.dominio.es/carpeta/imagen.png" download target='_blanck'> <img src='img/descarga.png'> </a>`

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No es `_blank`?

Comment: Tienes razon, se me ha colado la c, pero en el codigo esta bien escrito.